# Выбор БД для проекта с сложной структурой данных

Tags: база-данных, django, nosql

Начал делать проект на Django. Имеются следующие данные в JSON (привожу часть структуры, остальное повторяется):

```
[{"name": "Hydrogen", 
 "atomic_number": 1, 
 "symbol": "H", 
 "thermal": 
      {"absolute_boiling_point": { 
           "value": 234, 
           "unit": "K"}, 
       "heat_of_vaporization": {
           "value": {"p": 4, "M": 0.452, "n": 10},  
           "unit": "kJ/mol"}}}]
```

Для наглядности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что структура довольно сложная и многократно вложенная.

Элемент обладает свойствами без группы (типа, Name, symbol, atomic_number, которых около десяти и они являются общими для всех элементов) и группами свойств (групп имеется несколько десятков, в каждую из которых входит также несколько десятков свойств).

Как видно значение свойств может быть представлено строкой, десятичным число и инженерной записью (для которой используется три числа - мантисса, основание, степень)

Возникла проблема - я не могу описать эту структуру через реляционную БД проекта (postgresql), не могу установить связи.

**Подойдет мне реляционная БД? Или следует обратить внимание на noSQL решения? Правильные я выбрал инструменты для реализации проекта?**

Создал модели для элемента

```css
class Element(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Element'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Elements'

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(verbose_name="Symbol", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Различных форм записи

```css
class ScientificNotation(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Scientific Notation'

    significand = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Significand", blank=True, null=True)
    base = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Base", blank=True, null=True)
    exponent = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Exponent", blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(verbose_name="Unit", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

```css
class DecimalNotation(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Decimal Notation'

    value = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Value", blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(verbose_name="Unit", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Группы свойств. С этой моделью и возникает проблема.

```css
class ThermalProperties(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Thermal properties'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Thermal properties'

    element = OneToOneField(Element)
    melting_point = ForeignKey(ScientificNotation)
    boiling_point = ForeignKey(ScientificNotation)
    heat_of_vaporization = ForeignKey(DecimalNotation)
```

Я не могу ссылаться на одну и ту же модель (в конкретном примере ScientificNotation)

```
 ERRORS:
 table.ThermalProperties.boiling_point: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'ThermalProperties.boiling_point' clashes with reverse accessor for 'ThermalProperties.melting_point'.
 HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'ThermalProperties.boiling_point' or 'ThermalProperties.melting_point'.
```

**И продублирую вопрос здесь, если кто-то дочитал. Подойдет мне реляционная БД? Правильные я выбрал инструменты для реализации проекта?**

Comment: добавил уточнение, что исходные данные в формате JSON. Элемент обладает свойствами без группы (типа, Name, symbol, atomic_number, которых около десяти и они являются общими для всех элементов) и группами свойств (групп имеется несколько десятков, в каждую из которых входит также несколько десятков свойств). То есть в итоге общее число свойств будет сотнями

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хороший вопрос, я даже рад пожертвовать час на написание ответа :)

Как бы не громко звучал заголовок, но эта **структура больше простая, чем сложная.**

### Реляционная структура

**Почти любую структуру можно описать в реляционной базе данных, хоть она и будет достаточно жетской**

Прошу заметить, что в реляционных базах данных тоже есть патерны проектирования, и давайте попробуем сначала реализовать один из правильных патернов, называющихся Class Table Inheritance. Он гарантирует размещение разных элементов в разных таблицах, в которых они должны находится:

1. **element** - структура для элементов

   - name
   - atomic_number
   - symbol
2. **element_thermal** - структура для параметров

   - atomic_number
   - type
   - unit
3. **element_thermal_mol** - структура для параметров mol/kg

   - atomic_number
   - p
   - M
   - n
4. **element_thermal_value** - структура для обычных параметров

   - atomic_number
   - value

Здесь в зависимости от unit'а требуется выбирать таблицу, которую нужно будет делать JOIN. Мы здесь используем подход разделения данных на таблицы, который полностью соответствует реляционной структуре и ее правилам, но с каждым новым типом и данными Вам придется добавлять новую таблицу и усложнять сохранения и бизнес логику.

Ок. Попробуем подход Entity-Attributes-Values (EAV), его часто называют анти-паттерном проектирования из-за отсутствия контроля типа, контроля данных, размещения данных в одной таблице и т.д и вообще это выворачивание реляционной структуры наизнанку, но сам подход на небольших данных достаточно хорошо себя проявляет.

1. **element** - структура для элементов

   - name
   - atomic_number
   - symbol
2. **element_thermal** - структура для параметров

   - atomic_number
   - type
   - unit
3. **element_thermal_values** - структура для всех параметров

   - atomic_number
   - parameter_type
   - value

По сути, здесь все свои значения параметров вы храните в element_thermal_values записывая в parameter_type название параметра (INT, P, M, N), после чего делайте JOIN этой таблицы и получаете все параметры и обрабатываете их, запрос на получение данных всегда один, но естественно контроль должен быть обеспечен на уровне кода.

На маленьком проекте не будет разницы в том, что вы выберете, второй вариант просто проще, первый правильнее.

Да по сути, можно вообще не создавать отдельную таблицу, а просто запихнуть данные в value в виде json, просто с ними нельзя будет работать и как-то выполнять запросы, поэтому этот подход не всегда правильный, хотя базы типа PostgreSQL позволяют производить какие-то операции на уровне JSON.

### NoSQL (Неструктурированные базы)

Хотите использовать noSQL, используйте. Никто Вас в этом не ограничивает и ваша структура, в некоторой степени являющейся динамичной, будет подходить для MongoDB, когда вы будете использовать все прелести документ-ориентированного подхода. Сам ваш элемент выглядит как документ.

Если у данных нет связей или их очень мало с другими данными, то в целом NoSQL (MongoDB) отличный выбор для вашей задачи и сможет упростить в некоторой степени работу с данными.

**В целом размер кода будет примерно одинаковый**, т.к. обработчики на value при выводе или процессинге все равно придется писать.

### Вывод

**Я рекомендую Вам попробовать несколько подходов**, начните с нового MongoDB, потом попробуйте грамотное наследование в реляционных таблицах, сравните плюсы и минусы тех или иных реализаций и посмотрите что подходит для вас, опыта меньше не станет.

MongoDB заинтересует Вас тем, что это база данных по сути в которой данные хранятся в виде доступном приложению (JSON) и изменяемой структурой данных, которая тоже имеет плюсы и минусы, из плюсов конечно еще масштабируемость.

Старый подход на SQL отлично решает вопросы построения систем, где нужна целостность данных, соблюдение ACID, тяжелые запросы на объединение с многими таблицами.

В двух подходах есть минусы и плюсы, в своем случае, **если бы я писал систему которая содержала периодическую таблицу** и мне хотелось бы пощупать новые технологии, я бы взял MongoDB и познал бы Map-Reduce и т.д.

---

Мы часто используем Mongo для данных, чью структуру тяжело предусмотреть, например **логирование** в виде истории действий пользователя с различными типами параметров, конечно было бы хорошо запихнуть это в MySQL, но желания создавать отдельную таблицу под определенные данные просто нет, а использование подхода EAV на большом объеме данных просто уничтожает всю **производительность**, в MongoDB же есть хорошая масштабируемость и изменяемая структура данных, поэтому плюсы перевешивают минусы.

Comment: Реляционная бд вполне позволяет хранить нереляционные данные (для постгреса есть тип JSON, JSONB). По ним можно строить индексы, искать, доставать отдельные значения, про внешние ключи не скажу, не пробовал. Т.е. все реляционные данные хранть реляционно, а если вреляционную модель ложится плохо - делать поле с json.

Comment: Спасибо, за развернутый ответ, вы меня заставили по другому взглянуть на проект.

Comment: Добавил уточнение к вопросу и немного поправил его без изменения основной мысли. У каждого элемента будет сотни свойств и десятки групп, в которые эти свойства вложены. Поэтому CTI подход будет слишком сложен - придется создавать новую таблицу для каждого свойства, как я понял из вашего ответа. Второй подход не подойдет, так как структура слишком сложная

Comment: А вот вариантом с MongoDB вы меня заинтриговали и дали направление, буду пробовать

Answer (score 1):

> Подойдет мне реляционная БД?

Да вполне подойдёт.

> У каждого элемента будет сотни свойств и десятки групп, в которые эти свойства вложены. (часть принадлежит самому элементу, часть группам свойств, которые в свою очередь принадлежат элементу)

**Ваша задача выглядит как задача про отношения. То есть, я считаю, что реляционная БД подойдёт лучше, чем нереляционная.**

> Правильные я выбрал инструменты для реализации проекта?

Всегда есть несколько способов решить одну и ту же задачу.

> Как видно значение свойств может быть представлено строкой, десятичным число и инженерной записью (для которой используется три числа - мантисса, основание, степень)

Можно ещё решить задачу с помощью [фреймворка для обобщённых связей](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) в django

---

> Я не могу ссылаться на одну и ту же модель (в конкретном примере ScientificNotation)

Ну естесственно не можете. ForeignKey определяет отношение один-ко-многим, между таблицами(объектами), а вы зачем-то попытались определить его два раза к одной таблице.

Можно было, например, сделать дополнительную таблицу.

---

Вариантов решения вашей задачи не один.

У вас есть элемент, и способы его записи.
Разные типы записей можно реализовать через классы.

```
class Element(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Element'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Elements'

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(verbose_name="Symbol", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


class DecimalNotationElement(Element):  # Наследумеся от элемента!
    """
    Наследуясь от Element, в Джанге, автоматически создаётся
    отношение один_к_одному.
    """
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Decimal Notation'

    value = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Value", blank=True, null=True)
    unit = models.CharField(verbose_name="Unit", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


# Работать будет так:
element = DecimalNotationElement.objects.create(
    name="lalala",
    symbol="S",
    value=num,
    unit="some unit"
)
# То есть просто обращаемся к нужному полю, и уже не играет
# роли что поля из разных классов.
>>>element = DecimalNotationElement.objects.get(name="lalala")
>>>element.name
>>>'lalala'
>>>element.unit
>>>'some unit'
```

Comment: Добавил уточнение к вопросу и немного поправил его без изменения основной мысли. У каждого элемента будет сотни свойств и десятки групп, в которые эти свойства вложены. Структура не ограничена, изображением на схеме. Следовательно, ваше решение, если я его правильно понял, не сможет описать. Например, элемент может обладать несколькими значениями в десятичной записи (часть принадлежит самому элементу, часть группам свойств, которые в свою очередь принадлежат элементу)

Comment: Ну, тогда всё упрощается. Берите РСУБД, и не мучайтесь.

Comment: Добавил это в ответ.

Comment: В еще одном ответе @Firepro и моих комментариях к нему пришли к выводу, что каждое новое свойство заставит создавать новую таблицу. А количество свойств исчисляется сотнями, структура будет нереально усложняться

Comment: Пока что решение РСУБД в качестве запасного варианта отложу и буду держать на бумаге

Comment: >каждое новое свойство заставит создавать новую таблицу

Comment: И еще пояснение в вашему решению, DecimalNotation не связано с самим элементом, а связано с свойством элемента (плотность, вес, точка кипения)

Comment: Плохое решение плодить таблицы: свойства разные, а поля для хранения одинаковые. Свойства можно задать константами, и все дела.

Comment: да, "заставит создавать таблицу", мы же говорим о реляционном подходе, но их количество будет разрастаться, думаю, это не самый адекватный подход

Comment: "Плохое решение плодить таблицы: свойства разные, а поля для хранения одинаковые. Свойства можно задать константами, и все дела" ------------- ну, схема свойства везде одинакова, например, два похожих свойства: температура кипения - 500 К, температура плавления - 350 К. свойства разные, но используют дестичную запись числа. так же я могу их записать в инженерной форме и поменять единицу измерения. температура кипения - 5,0^10(2) C, температура плавления - 3,5^10(2) C.

Comment: http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/models/fields.html#choices

Comment: да, спасибо) о чойзах знаю

Comment: Ну а чего тогда за проблемы? :)

Comment: голова кипит от отношений